# How to traverse 2 rows into a single row based on values of a single column

Tags: sql

I have a to club the values present in a column of my table , based on the values they have in a different column.

For example

```
--------------------------------------------- 
Col1.         |       Col 2.               |
Bokaro            Sector 9
Dhanbad.        Sector 29
Bokaro            Sector 11
Dhanbad         Sector 30
Ranchi.            Sector 50
```

I want this to be displayed as

```
Col1.                  Col2
---------------------------------------------------------
Bokaro.            Sector 9      Sector 11
Dhanbad.         Sector 29.   Sector 30
Ranchi.             Sector 50
```

How to do this in a SQL query .

Comment: How many `Col2` values can a given `Col1` value have?

Comment: which database are you using?

Comment: If you are using `mysql`, look into using `group_concat`.  Other databases support similar methods -- lots of examples on SO already for this though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simulating group\_concat MySQL function in SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL server, use STUFF function.

```
  SELECT  y1.Col1
   ,STUFF((SELECT '  ' + y2.Col2 [text()]
     FROM YourTable y2 
     WHERE y1.col1 =y2.col1
     FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
    .value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,' ') [Col2]
FROM YourTable y1
GROUP BY y1.col1
```